# Im stuck on this question..is there a formula for this?

Tags: graph-theory

"Suppose G is a graph with 19 vertices and 154 edges. Show that G is connected."

Comment: Do you want to show any effort of your own to answer this question?

Comment: what if the graph has loops?

Answer (score 2):

Assume to the contrary that there exists a graph $G$ with $n=19$ vertices and $m\geq 154$ edges that is not connected. We may assume that $G$ has exactly two components $G_1$ and $G_2$ with order $n_1$ and $n_2$ respectively, since if otherwise, we can just add edges to $G$ until it does. Then $G$ has at most $$\binom{n_1}2+\binom{n_2}2$$ edges where $n_1+n_2=19$. This is maximized when $n_1=1$ and $n_2=18$(or the other way around) in which case $$\binom{n_1}2+\binom{n_2}2=153$$ contradicting the assumption that $m\geq 154$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the result that every simple undirected graph with more than $$\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}$$ edges is connected. n is the number of vertices.

Comment: How do you arrive at this result?

Comment: With n being the number of vertices?

Comment: How does this result apply for a graph that's not assumed to be simple?

Comment: Yes n is the number of vertices. We can prove this using the complete graph. Start with a complete graph, with size $$\frac {n(n − 1)}{2}$$. Remove n − 1 edges incident on one vertex. The resulting graph has $$(n − 1)[n/2 − 1]}$$ edges. Now, if G is not connected divide into 2 subgraphs of size say s and n-s. The maximum number of edges for the two graphs n(n −1)/2−s(n −s).
Now the minimum is for s = 1 (using concept of calculus) which gives the desired result.